# Porting Azure connectivity sample to a windows store javascript navigation app

Tags: azure, winjs, azure-mobile-services

Am working on a windows store javascript application. The application will be using data from azure. When I tried to port the azure connectivity sample to a navigation template, the list view displayed the entire columns from the table. I used the same data read code from the sample. The html page and css were identical to the sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--head segment-->
<title>QuickStart</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->    
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MobileServicesJavaScriptClient/MobileServices.js"></script>
<!-- QuickStart references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script src="/pages/Advertisement/advertisement.js"></script>
<link href="/pages/Advertisement/advertisement.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
</head>
<body>
<!--body segment-->
<div style="margin: 50px 10px 10px 50px" id="overalldiv">
<div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr; -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr;">

<div style="-ms-grid-column-span: 2; margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;">
<div style="color: #0094ff; font-size: 8pt">WINDOWS AZURE MOBILE SERVICES</div>
<div style="color: #808080; font-size: 32pt">Sample</div>
</div>

        <div style="-ms-grid-row: 2; -ms-grid-column: 1;">
            <div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr">
                <div style="-ms-grid-column: 1;" class="tasknumber">
                    1
                </div>
                <div style="-ms-grid-column: 2">
                    <strong>Insert a TodoItem</strong><br />
                    <span style="font-size: small">Enter some text below and click Save to insert a new todo item into your database</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 72px; -ms-grid-column: 2">
                <input type="text" id="textInput" />
                <button id="buttonSave" style="margin-left: 5px">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="-ms-grid-column: 2; -ms-grid-row: 2;">
            <div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr">
                <div style="-ms-grid-row: 1">
                    <div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr">
                        <div style="-ms-grid-column: 1; float: left;" class="tasknumber">
                            2
                        </div>
                        <div style="-ms-grid-column: 2">
                            <strong>Query and Update Data</strong><br />
                            <span style="font-size: small">Click refresh below to load the unfinished TodoItems from your database. Use the checkbox to complete and update your TodoItems</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 72px">
                        <button id="buttonRefresh">Refresh</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="TemplateItem" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                <div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr">
                    <input class="itemCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-win-bind="checked: complete; dataContext: this" />
                    <div style="-ms-grid-column: 2; -ms-grid-row-align: center; margin-left: 5px" data-win-bind="innerText: text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="listItems" style="-ms-grid-row: 2; margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; -ms-grid-row-align: stretch"
                data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: TemplateItem, layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout} }">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The actual sample project displayed only the text field from the azure database table as shown in the below diagram. 
[image: Screenshot of the Actual Sample Output]

But in my case all the column fields are getting displayed
[image: Screenshot of my application output]

How am I supposed to display only the required content and how am I supposed to do the formatting for the listview contents. I wanted to display the contents in the following manner

1 
ab

2 
drag

3 
dragon

4
arm
..
..
..

Comment: what did you try and what didn't work? You have to apply template to the listItems WinControl to instruct how to diplsay the items. Apparently the default one will just display the raw item data, which is JSON.

Comment: I have applied the item template but still the complete raw contents are getting displayed. The binding of item template to the listview is not happening. The only change that I have done is to the javascript file and have shown the code over here:
http://goo.gl/mxbHk

Comment: As an answer to your forum's question suggest - post the real HTML here (and there). Not in comment, but in the question space. properly formatted.

Comment: astaykov. I have updated the question with the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the [itemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700705.aspx) for the ListView? You need to tell the ListView how to display each item of the itemDataSource

Comment: I have done that too. But still the complete raw contents are getting displayed. Check out the below div.

    <div id="TemplateItem" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr">
    <input class="itemCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-win-bind="checked: complete; dataContext: this" />
    <div style="-ms-grid-column: 2; -ms-grid-row-align: center; margin-left: 5px" data-win-bind="innerText: text">
    </div>
    </div>
                </div>

Comment: that's the div for the template, then you need to 'tell' the ListView to use that template... aren't you missing that?